# email component cakephp

Tags: email, cakephp, components

First time using the email component... I followed the book instruction and I set this

```
function sendNewUserMail($id) {
    $User = $this->User->read(null,$id);
    $this->Email->to = array('MyEmai@gmail.com'); 
    $this->Email->from = 'MyEmai@gmail.com';
    $this->Email->subject = 'Welcome to our really cool thing';
    $this->Email->template = 'simple_message'; 

    $this->Email->sendAs = 'text'; 
    $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
        'port'=>'465', 
        'timeout'=>'30',
        'auth' => true,
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'username'=>'MyEmail@gmail.com',
        'password'=>'*********'   
    );
    $this->set('User', $User);
    $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
    $this->Email->send();
    $this->set('smtp_errors', $this->Email->smtpError);
 }
```

I try to run the method, but nothing happens... I created the layouts, the elements, and put `var $component = array('Email');`

I'm getting this error

> Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable
>   it when you configured PHP?: 16

by the way I at home so no firewalls, no blocking etc

Answer (score 0):

Gmail smtp requires a secure connection and it looks like your PHP configuration doesn't have ssl enabled. Open php.ini and look for a line that looks like

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

or

```
#extension=openssl.so
```

and uncomment it (remove the ; or the #), then restart PHP.

If you can't find such line there you may need to install OpenSSL first.